# How can I get particular count of extreme points from a static image even after resizing it in python?

Tags: python, opencv

I need to obtain a particular count of extreme points for static image,even after resizing it.
I used contour technique to take extreme points,code is,

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("/home/sharon/Documents/orbec/resized_cloth.png")

gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, threshold_image = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# cv2.imshow("threshold_image", threshold_image)
# import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
selected_contour = max(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(selected_contour, 0.0035 * cv2.arcLength(selected_contour, True), True)
ShoulderR = approx[1][0][0]
ShoulderL = approx[17]
HipR = approx[7]
HipL = approx[11]
print(approx)

cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 255), 5)

for point in approx:
    x, y = point[0]
    string = str(x) + " " + str(y)
    cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 2, (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(image, string, (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0))

cv2.imwrite("cordinate_image.jpg", image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Iam getting extreme points with the above code and it is working for every static images. I need to use each extreme points to put my algorithm.
My input image is,

[image]

Each point iam getting using index of variable approx variable(from above code). But after resizing the image, position is changing,
For example before resize my len(approx) was equal to 20,but after resizing it changes to 22. In contour the index value will change based on shapes. But is there any techniques to obtain constant length of it? Because iam using the x,y values to my algorithm using approx[0],approx[10]..etc. So it should be constant. If approx[0] denotes shoulder point it should be after resizing also.

####UPDATE2###################################################################
I have done rescaling using the below code,

```
scale_ratio = shoulder_length/shoulder_height
# scale_ratio = int(scale_ratio)
####coordinate value taking from images with white background
# ###---------------------------------------------------------
im2 = Image.fromarray(resized_cloth)
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, threshold_image = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# cv2.imshow("threshold_image", threshold_image)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
selected_contour = max(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(selected_contour, 0.0048 * cv2.arcLength(selected_contour, True), True)
resized_approx = approx * scale_ratio
# resized_approx = int(resized_approx)
resized_approx = [[[int(float(j)) for j in i] for i in k] for k in resized_approx]
resized_approx = numpy.array(resized_approx)
row,col,channels = numpy.shape(image)
blank_image = numpy.zeros((row,col,3), numpy.uint8)
cv2.fillPoly(blank_image, pts =[resized_approx], color=(255,255,255))

cv2.drawContours(blank_image, [resized_approx], 0, (0, 0, 255), 5)
```

I rescaled and got constant number of extreme points. My another problem is I need the resized image also.
The rescaled contour be look like,
[image]

So only contour got rescaled,but I need the image too within the contour. I checked Bitwise operation and it wont work with this. Any solutions?

Comment: Scale the vertex coordinates rather than computing them again. Just multiply them by the resize fraction.

Comment: Hey Thanks! Iam new to opencv. Could you please show some examples? @fmw42

Comment: Hi @fmw42 i found a relevant link https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/tutorial-how-to-scale-and-rotate-contours-in-opencv-using-python-f48be59c35a2     And the method is understandable. But how can I give scale varibale? My code is cv2.resize(image,(shoulder_height,shoulder_length)). So how can I obtain scaling factor to multiply?

Comment: You know the shoulder_height,shoulder_length from the original and your desired values in the resize. The scales are the ratios between original and desired.

Comment: @fmw42  Can you check my update 2. I got the rescaled contour with constant set of extreme points but no idea how to get rescaled image. Can you help me on that?

Comment: My suggestion was to compute your contour at original resolution. Then resize your image by some fraction. Then given the resize fraction, scale the vertices of your contour by the same fraction. Then draw the new contour from the vertices using cv2.polylines(). See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga1ea127ffbbb7e0bfc4fd6fd2eb64263c

Comment: Can you show me some examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example in Python/OpenCV where I scale the image by 0.5 and the vertices of the polygon by 0.5.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# set scale factor
scale = 0.5

# load image
img = cv2.imread("diamond.png")

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold to binary
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# get the largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# reduce number of vertices to 4
peri = cv2.arcLength(big_contour, True)
vertices = cv2.approxPolyDP(big_contour, 0.05 * peri, True)
print(len(vertices))
for vertex in vertices:
    print(vertex)

# draw vertices as polyline on copy of input
polygon_full_res = img.copy()
cv2.polylines(polygon_full_res, [vertices], True, (0,0,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

# resize image
img_small = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=scale, fy=scale)

# resize vertices
print('')
new_vertices = []
for vertex in vertices:
    xx = int(scale * vertex[0][0])
    yy = int(scale * vertex[0][1])
    new_vertex = [xx,yy]
    new_vertices.append(new_vertex)

# convert list of points to numpy array of points
vertex_array = np.array([new_vertices])
print(vertex_array)

# draw new_vertices as polyline on copy of resized image
polygon_low_res = img_small.copy()
cv2.polylines(polygon_low_res, [vertex_array], True, (0,0,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("polygon_full_res.png", polygon_full_res)
cv2.imwrite("polygon_low_res.png", polygon_low_res)

# display it
cv2.imshow("polygon_full_res", polygon_full_res)
cv2.imshow("polygon_low_res", polygon_low_res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Input with polygon drawn:

[image]

Vertex Coordinates:

```
[[232  21]]
[[ 21 233]]
[[233 444]]
[[444 232]]
```

Downsized image with polygon drawn on it:

[image]

Downsized vertex coordinates:

```
[[[116  10]
  [ 10 116]
  [116 222]
  [222 116]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still i have a confusion. You gave your scale ratio as 0.5. But in my case it will change depends on the length and height of inputs. I cannot set a default value 0.5. Even I checked with length/height. But it doesnot matches. Can you please explain this?For example I have 4 lengths and 4 heights for 4 images,how can I give scale factor here? Thanks!

Comment: I used 0.5 as an example. I assumed that you just wanted to get the vertices scaled when the image is scaled. You can use any scale. But if you are trying to change the spacing between vertices with different values, then my solution is not what you want. Please clarify your question further. Apparently I misunderstood what you are trying to do.

Comment: I can explain. I have a cloth image to resize and to findout contour values. Each time i will get different length and height to resize the image. In each time when it get resized I need contour values but in same position, U can see 17 contour values in the above coloured t-shirt image. So after resize I need same number of contour values in the same position. My problem after resizing my image each time is the contour position is getting changed and number of points also varying. I need each positioned contour  value of resized image for my algorithm. I need fixed contour number and position

Comment: I am using polygons like contours and vertices of the polygons remain fixed in number when resizing. It is possible to resize differently in width and height, that is scaleX and scaleY are different with changes to my code.